# Busqueda en Python tipo Grep

Tags: python-3.x

Estimadxs buenas tardes, no estoy pudiendo encontrar la forma de buscar archivos (audios) con un patrón que seria el día y un numero asignado. En linux lo hacia fácil con el comando 'find'

`find /var/spool/asterisk/monitor/2021/* -type f \( -name "out-*-201228-$DIA-*" -o -name "out-*-201614-$DIA-*"`

Pero en Python, si bien estoy iniciándome no estoy encontrando la manera.

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: no entiendo bien, quieres buscar un archivo con python o quieres ejecutar el comando para buscar el archivo en python??

Comment: Primero crea un código que recorra un directorio listando los archivos. Hay cientos de tutoriales al respecto. Luego, ya teniendo los nombres de los archivos, ocupas expresiones regulares para extraer el día y número. Ahí puedes chequear si los tienen o no, o si son del día que te interesa.

Comment: Christian como estas? la idea seria encontrar un método en python para hacer la búsqueda con el patrón ese que estoy haciendo en bash.

Comment: puedes usar el módulo `os` de python para ejecutar un comando seria algo `os.system("comando")`

Comment: @Christian pude listar con una variable 'directorio = "E:/WAV/out-*-201634-*.wav"', pero al querer agregar otro patch u otro nombre en esa variable me patea fuerte.

Comment: y como haces para agregar el otro path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el comando `os.walk(directorio)` te va regresando el nombre del archivo, puedes hacer una expresión regular delo que necesitas o utilizar el comodín *, aqui te dejo una [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293968/how-do-i-search-directories-and-find-files-that-match-regex) y un ejemplo:

```
import os 
import re
directorioActual=os.getcwd()
print directorioActual
os.chdir(/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/)



for folder , sub_folders , files in os.walk("Example_Top_Level"):
 print("Actual directorio folder: "+ folder)
 print('\n')
 print("pintamos los subforlders: ")
 for sub_fold in sub_folders:
    print("\t Subfolder: "+sub_fold )

 pattern = 'out-*-201614-$DIA-*'
 result = re.search(pattern, file)
 print(result)
```

Comment: +1 por el gran ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

@betovaz81 como estas? Desde ya muchas gracias por la respuesta.
Con la funcion Glob, encontré que me liste los archivos, pero no logro que me liste varios patrones (ej: Directorio2)

```
from glob import glob

directorio = "E:/WAV/out-*-201634-*.wav"
#directorio2 = [ E:/WAV/out-*-201634-*.wav, E:/WAV/out-*-201633-*.wav ] 
# **La idea es buscar mas patrones como en esta variable.**


def listar_archivos(ruta):
    listar_audios = glob(ruta)
    return listar_audios




input = listar_archivos(directorio)

for f in input:

    print(f)
```

Comment: Si tienes problemas edita tu pregunta poniendo lo que has hecho y el inconveniente que tienes